# How do I create a dropdown of the valid values set by validates_inclusion_of?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, dry, validation

I have a `User` model object whose `permission` attribute is restricted by `validates_inclusion_of` to `['user','org_admin','site_admin']`.  When designing the create/edit form for this object, I don't want to duplicate this list, in case it changes later.  Is there a "Rails way" to do this, or should I just extract the list of valid values into an attribute accessible from outside of the instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I really wanted to work with strings I would probably define a User::PERMISSIONS constance which includes the mentioned permissions.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  PERMISSIONS = ['user','org_admin','site_admin']
  validates_inclusion_of :permission, :in => PERMISSIONS
end
```

A simplified form (using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) in the example)

```
simple_form_for(@user) do |f|
  f.input :permission, :as => :select, :collection => User::PERMISSIONS
end
```

It would be even neater to create a permissions model and just save the permission_id when you create a new user.

There are probably even better ways to do it so I'm looking forward to other answers.

Comment: This is how I'm doing it right now, but I wasn't sure if that was the "Railsiest" way.  By the way, I didn't know about the ":as => :select" thing; that's pretty awesome!  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Well that :as => :select will only work if you are using simple or semantic forms, just to clear that up if it wasn't clear! :) I hope we get some different opinions to see if there is a better way to do it.